# Access header property after API call to Node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my react project, I make an api call to my Node backend endpoint. In this endpoint I return a response with an `x-auth-token` header set. The code for the
response is shown below:

```
res.header('x-auth-token', token).send('User registered')
```

In react, I make an api call to this endpoint and I need to extract the `x-auth-token` and set the value of it in local storage. I try doing this however there is no header being sent with the response.

Here is a snippet of the code for the api call in react:

```
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/', {username: username, email: email, password: password})
    console.log(response.headers.get('x-auth-token'))
```

In the console I get:

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:5000/api/users/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

And when I console log `response.headers`, in the console, I get this returned:

```
{content-length: "15", content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"}
content-length: "15"
content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
__proto__: Object
```

Does anybody know the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Issue is that your endpoint is not responding correctly.

Comment: right, backend issue

Answer (score 1):

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:5000/api/users/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

First you have to ensure this endpoint works properly. It is not. Fix this before trying to get the auth token.

Check that your server expects a POST call, and that the body is in proper format.